# IFrame alternatives

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Is there anything else I could use instead of an iframe on my web page by where I still need to pass a url or is iframe it?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you displaying in the iFrames? External pages or just content from your webside and you dont want to reload the whole page on each action on the page?

Comment: It would help if you let us know what you don't like about IFRAME.

Comment: Hi. Content is all internal/intranet related and not cross domain. Secondly, most users using the web app do not appreciate windows within windows. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Since you put jQuery as a tag I suggest you either look at http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an ajax request to fetch the content and then just inject it into the page but that won't work cross domain, so if you're trying to host external content iframe is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a div and fill this div in multiple ways, either do an ajax request or if you're using any server scripting language you can just do an include inside the div.

using iframes is still the cleanest options for most uses.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell us a bit more about what you're trying to do so we can help you out a bit more.

It sounds like an HTTP Request/AJAX might fit the bill, but its hard to say at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other option for crossdomain embedding unless you use the HTML `<frameset>` element, which I strongly do not recommend. You can, however, hide the iframe using CSS.

[Crossdomain communication](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) can be done in a variety of ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything else you can use, as an alternative to an iframe.
Considering the fact, that the URL will change upon clicking on any link inside the iframe, will change the content. This, otherwise can be a tedious and challenging. The moment you click a link, you are bound to be redirected to it. Hence, no.